# CakePHPで違うテーブルから紐付いたデータを取得する

Tags: cakephp

**RoomsController**

```
public function index() {
    $this->Room->recursive = 0;
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate = array(
        'Room' =>
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            $this->Room->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs),
        )
    ));
    $this->set('rooms', $this->paginate());
}
```

debug($rooms);

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Room' => array(
        'id' => '0001',
        'room_id' => '1234',
        'name' => 'hogehoge',
        'area_id' => 'tko1234',
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Room' => array(
        'id' => '0002',
        'room_id' => '1235',
        'name' => 'fugafuga',
        'area_id' => 'osk1234',
    )
)
```

とあった場合、

```
<?php foreach ($rooms as $roos): ?>
$rooms['Room']['area_id'];
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

で出力される`'tko1234'`, `'osk1234'`に対してこちらで用意しているAreaテーブルと連携させてエリア名をそれぞれ`'東京'`、`'大阪'`と出力させるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

**Areaテーブル**

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Area' => array(
        'id' => 'tko1234',
        'name' => '東京',
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Area' => array(
        'id' => 'osk1234',
        'name' => '大阪',
    )
))
```

となっています。
初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

アソシエーションという機能を使います。質問の内容であれば、belongs toのアソシエーションを設定します。

CakePHPでの実際の手順はマニュアルを参照してください

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Answer (score 1):

`app/Model/Room.php`を作成して、そこに

```
<?php
   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

   class Room extends AppModel {
      public $belongsTo = array('Area');
   }
```

`app/Model/Area.php`を作成して、

```
<?php
   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

   class Area extends AppModel {
      public $hasMany = array('Room');
   }
```

でどうですか？